# Can't install sox on raspberry 4b

Tags: pi-4

Here is what I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install sox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sox' has no installation candidate
```

`apt-get update and apt-get upgrade` were done.

Anybody know what happens ?
Thanks,
Mathieu.

Edit:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt policy sox
sox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,a=testing,n=buster,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main,b=armhf
     origin archive.raspberrypi.org
 500 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable/main armhf Packages
     release o=coral-edgetpu,a=coral-edgetpu-stable,n=coral-edgetpu-stable,l=coral-edgetpu,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.cloud.google.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Pls add the output of `apt policy sox` and `apt policy` to your question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you managed to remove (or overwrite) /etc/apt/sources.list
This contains the link to the Raspbian repo.

By default it contains:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Restore this file (or add the above to your version of the file) and then run `sudo apt update` to update the package info. I would also run `sudo apt full-upgrade` to make sure you're fully up to date again.

After that you can try to install sox again.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I don't know what happened to my sources.list, but i had a directory sources.list.d...